# Ubuntu Server fails "apt-get update" after fresh install

Tags: server, updates, synaptics

I'm trying to set up my old Thinkpad R500 as an Ubuntu homeserver. Installation (w/o any snaps, with full encryption) went smooth. But as soon as I try to `sudo apt-get update` after restart I get **mergelists error**. I tried `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` But when I go on with `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update` I get an **segmentation fault**.

I tried it several times, always with the same result.

I got Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 from the offical Ubuntu HP. Checked integrity and dd'ed it to a USB falshdrive. Hardware-wise the R500 is upgraded with 250GB SSD and 8GB RAM which ran until now without problems under Ubuntu Desktop. I also checked the SSD with S.M.A.R.T. without any problems. To square it up I did a `shred` of the whole drive.

I'm very thankful for any advice.

I try to provide logs as soon as possible.

--edit: The R500 has 8GB RAM (which are supported by some models)  not 16... must have drifted off to an other Laptop while writing...

Comment: According to the specifications https://support.lenovo.com/nz/en/solutions/pd005118 it supports **up to 4GB RAM**.

Comment: Have you tried to run Memtest86+ first?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that I've contributed to the clutter of unnecessary questions.

Of course it was a faulty RAM ...as you suspected...
Memtest over night showed multiple errors.

Thanks for your comments!